# Android app reading device information in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions

How can i get these items below to read that data from the device and Display in in my html page below?

```
  $('#devicename').html(device.name);
  $('#devicephonegap').html(device.phonegap);
  $('#devicplatform').html(device.platform);
  $('#deviceuuid').html(device.uuid);
  $('#deviceversion').html(device.version);
```

Full page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#newpage", function () {
        $('#saveButton').click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("name", $('#name').val());
        });


    });
    var wID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSucess, onerror, { frequency: 1000 });
    function onSucess(a) {
        $('#aX').html(a.x);
        $('#aY').html(a.y);
        $('#aZ').html(a.z);
        $('#aTime').html(a.timestamp);
    }
    function onError() {

    }
var phoneName = window.device.name;
var phoneName = device.name;
        $('#devicename').html(device.name);
        $('#devicephonegap').html(device.phonegap);
        $('#devicplatform').html(device.platform);
        $('#deviceuuid').html(device.uuid);
        $('#deviceversion').html(device.version);


    $(document).on('pageshow', '#newpage', function () {
        var personName = localStorage.getItem("name");
        if (personName.length > 0) {
            $('#name').val(personName);
        }
    });
</script>
<title>Hello World 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home Page2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        hello Phone Gap and JQuery Mobile! 
        <a href="#newpage" data-role="button">new page</a>
        <br>
        <p id="devicename">  </p>
        <p id="devicephonegap">  </p>
        <p id="deviceplatform">  </p>
        <p id="deviceuuid">  </p>
        <p id="deviceversion">  </p>
         <p id="ax">  </p>
        <p id="ay">  </p>
        <p id="az">  </p>
        <p id="aTime">  </p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#dialogpage" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="plus">Add Something</a>

    </div>
</div>


<div id="newpage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#home" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a>
        <h1>New Page</h1>
        <a href=#home" data-icon="save">save</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="name">what is your name?</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" />
        <a id="saveButton" href="" data-role="button">Save</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>
            footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="dialogpage" data-role="page"> 
 <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>
     <div data-role="content">
        this is a dialog
     </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Device plugin and ask for the Android READ_PHONE_STATE permission. This is clearly documented at:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device_permissions

Comment: Thanks for the link. I do not have app/res/xml/plugins.xml its called config. It does have that line of code in it though. In my manifest I do have the read phone state permission.

Comment: Would these lines go above my code up above?                     // These reference the same `device`
var phoneName = window.device.name;
var phoneName = device.name;

Comment: Okay, now that I see your code I can see the problem. You need to wait for the deviceready event before you can access any PhoneGap API's or values.

Comment: Where is my device ready event? Im not sure what code bit determines that?

Comment: You are double dipping over on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159616/android-writing-phone-data-to-screen/13159958#comment17905822_13159958 try asking the question in one place for better answers.

Answer (score 1):

**-** You will need to add `READ_PHONE_STATE` **permission** to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: yep I have that. So I guess its not a permissions issue i have.