# Android writing phone data to screen

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

Im trying to write information about my phone to my app screen. What am i doing wrong below here?
I have the proper permissions set in my manifest. Im using Phonegap to develope the app. With Jquery.
The app lanuches it jsut doesn not display the phone information.

```
<p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
```

Full page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#newpage", function () {
        $('#saveButton').click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("name", $('#name').val());
        });

    });
    var wID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSucess, onerror, { frequency: 1000 });
    function onSucess(a) {
        $('#aX').html(a.x);
        $('#aY').html(a.y);
        $('#aZ').html(a.z);
        $('#aTime').html(a.timestamp);
    }
    function onError() {

    }

    $(document).on('pageshow', '#newpage', function () {
        var personName = localStorage.getItem("name");
        if (personName.length > 0) {
            $('#name').val(personName);
        }
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

    element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}

</script>

<title>Hello World 2</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="home" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home Page2</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        hello Phone Gap and JQuery Mobile! 
        <a href="#newpage" data-role="button">new page</a>
        <br>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
         <p id="ax">  </p>
        <p id="ay">  </p>
        <p id="az">  </p>
        <p id="aTime">  </p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#dialogpage" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="plus">Add Something</a>

    </div>
</div>


<div id="newpage" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#home" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a>
        <h1>New Page</h1>
        <a href=#home" data-icon="save">save</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="name">what is your name?</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" />
        <a id="saveButton" href="" data-role="button">Save</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>
            footer</h4>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="dialogpage" data-role="page"> 
 <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>
     <div data-role="content">
        this is a dialog
     </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is stored your code? Is in an Activity?

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand what your asking for. Completly new to this. Im using phone gap to develop an app.

Comment: Oups, sorry, my mistake, I thought that you are using the Android native developpment language. An advice, better use the Android device specific language than the phone gap framework, you will have much more possibilities.

Comment: I have not worked with JavaScript for a while but it looks like you might have some syntax issues? `$('#devicename').html(device.name);` should be `$('devicename').html(device.name);`. [Try](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/phonegap-startup-or-bootstrap-javascript-index-file) this tutorial in your HTML to verify that you get something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until you get the **`deviceready`** event from PhoneGap, otherwise you are requesting it before PhoneGap is actually initialized and ready to return data.  See the docs/example here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Comment: I added that code example with the device ready in it. All i get is Loading device properties... It never actually writes out the data.

Comment: Can you take jQuery out of the equation and just get to deviceready and set the info in the div. Once you are sure that is working add jQuery back in.

Comment: You've got the `<script>` block in the `<head>` section, although you have added `deviceready`, you left out the jQuery DOM ready check. Try further wrapping the contents of your `onDeviceReady()` in `$(function() { /*code*/ });`.